# Java PatternSyntaxException when replacing characters in a String object

Tags: java, regex, string

I am trying to create string of this list without the following character `, []` as will I want to replace all two spaces after deleting them.

I have tried the following but I am geting the error in the title.
**Simple:**

```
[06:15, 06:45, 07:16, 07:46]
```

**Result should look as this:**

```
06:15 06:45 07:16 07:46
```

**Code:**

```
List<String> value = entry.getValue();
String timeEntries = value.toString();
String after = timeEntries.replaceAll(",", " ");
String after2 = after.replaceAll("  ", " ");
String after3 = after2.replaceAll("[", "");
String after4 = after3.replaceAll("]", "");
```

Comment: Ok I found the answer `String after = timeEntries.replace(",", " ").replace("[","").replace("]","").replace("  "," ");`

Comment: In regex (the argument you pass to `replaceAll` is a regex), `[` and `]` must be escaped. Especially in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) replaces all occurrences that match a given **regular expression**. Since you just want to match a simple string, you should use [`replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence-) instead:

```
List<String> value = entry.getValue();
String timeEntries = value.toString();
String after = timeEntries.replace(",", " ");
String after2 = after.replace("  ", " ");
String after3 = after2.replace("[", "");
String after4 = after3.replace("]", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer the main question, if you use `replaceAll`, make sure your 1st argument is a valid regular expression. For your example, you can actually reduce it to 2 calls to `replaceAll`, as 2 of the substitutions are identical.

```
List<String> value = entry.getValue();
String timeEntries = value.toString();
String after = timeEntries.replaceAll("[, ]", " ");
String after2 = after.replaceAll("\\[|\\]", "");
```

But, it looks like you're just trying to concatenate all the elements of a String list together. It's much more efficient to construct this string directly, by iterating your list and using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html):

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

for (String timeEntry: entry.getValue()) {
  builder.append(timeEntry);
}

String after = builder.toString();
```